# Why am I getting a bad_function_call exception when using std::function as a comparison function object in std::map

Tags: c++11

I am getting a std::__1::bad_function_call: std::exception when I execute the code below.

I have tried initializing std::function in the constructor and initializing it directly when defined as a class variable. In both cases I get the aforementioned exception.

Note that if I define a function object (a class with a bool operator () function defined), the code works properly. How can I capture a lambda into std::function so that no exception is thrown? Also, what is causing the exception in the code below?

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
    foo() {cmp = [](const int &a, const int &b){return a > b;};}
    //function<bool(const int &a, const int &b)> cmp = [](const int &a, const int &b){return a > b;};
    function<bool(const int &a, const int &b)> cmp;
    map<int, int, decltype(cmp)> rbtree;
};

int main() {

  foo* obj = new foo();
  obj->rbtree[5] = 5;
  obj->rbtree[1] = 5;
  obj->rbtree[5] = 5;
}
```

Comment: You need to actually pass an instance of  `decltype(cmp)` to `rbtree`'s constructor. Otherwise it gets a default-initialized comparator - a null function. As in: `foo() : rbtree([](int a, int b){return a > b;}) {}` You also don't need `cmp` member - it doesn't appear to be used for anything.

Comment: I don't see the point of your `std::function` games though. It looks like all you want is `std::map<int, int, std::greater<int>> rbtree;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I get an error when I pass cmp to rbtree.                   
    testfunc.cpp:9:41: error: unknown type name 'cmp'
    map<int, int, decltype(cmp)> rbtree(cmp);

Comment: Also, it is not a game, but a test-case. the key of the map can be a complex type that will require a functor.

Comment: If you want to provide an initializer in the class body, the syntax is `map<int, int, decltype(cmp)> rbtree{cmp};` with braces. However, that's not going to work - it's too early, `cmp` hasn't been initialized yet, so you'll end up back where you started, with null comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
class foo {
public:
    using Cmp = function<bool(int a, int b)>;
    map<int, int, Cmp> rbtree { [](int a, int b){return a > b;} };
};
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/DJZ53295)